# passing an array of components definitions as props in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am interested in passing an array of react `Component`s as `props`

```
export default class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            {this.props.actions ? <td>{
                this.props.actions.map((f, k) => f(r, k))
                }</td> : ''}
            ...
        )
    }
}


const actions = [
    (row, index) => <RemoveTableAction row={row} key={index}/>
    (row, index) => <EditTableAction row={row} key={index}/>
]

<Table ... actions={actions} />
```

As you can see in this example, for each action I want to display, I need to manually instantiate the component and manually pass `row` and `index`.

I would like to pass just the component definition and handle all this logic in the `Table` component.

```
const actions = [RemoveTableAction, EditTableAction]

map((compDef, k) => <compDef key={k} row={r}/>)
```

How can I instantiate these components in the `Table` component?

Comment: you can use react children or renderProps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you are doing it

```
map((CompDef, k) => <CompDef key={k} row={r} />)
```

make sure that the **CompDef** variable inside the map starts with an uppercase letter

***EDIT***

Here is a better solution to provide flexibility to both components (use with care)

```
const actions = [<RemoveTableAction />, <EditTableAction />];

<Table ... actions={actions} />
```

And in Table.js:

```
export default class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            {this.props.actions ? <td>{
                this.props.actions.map(
                    (action, k) => 
                        react.cloneElement(action, {row: r, key: k})
                )
            }</td> : ''}
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

This way we can clone the element and override or add some props.
And no, there is no serious performance overhead.

For a more detailed documentation take a look at [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

Comment: This worked. But I think I will have to stick with the previous solution because it give you much more flexibility

Comment: @tzortzik I've added another solution, I think you would like to use it :)))